# Stationary Process versus limit of MA(q)

Tags: stationarity, arma, moving-average

The Wold representation says that any stationary process is equivalent to a MA($\infty$) process which, in turn, is the limit of a MA(q) process. Does that mean that anything that can be proved for an MA(q) immediately generalizes to any stationary process? I suspect this is not the case. but can't really come up with a counter-example.

Comment: For the process to be stationary there are conditions on the moving average parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proposition. Let $y_t$ be a series from $MA(q)$. Then for any $q$, there is $s$ such that $Cov(y_t,y_{t-s})=0$.

Obviously, the above proposition is true. But there is no such $s$ for $AR(1)$ process with non-zero AR coefficient.

Comment: Nice example, but you did not make any conclusion. Since it was not self-study, it makes sense to spell it out fully.

Comment: What conclusion? I provided an counter-example to the OP's question, which means that his hypothesis is false.

Comment: That's what I meant. This sentence was missing :)